# Sass: Function return value by screen

Tags: sass

It's possible create a function that return value based on screen width. 
My idea:

```
@function vw_pc( $num ) {
  @media screen and (max-width: 1920)
  {
    @return a;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1200)
  {
    @return b;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, since the Sass compiler is creating a static CSS code regardless of your screen.